# toggle ngbAccordion from typscript File

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-5, ng-bootstrap

I want toggle the accordion from my component.ts file with a Button, how should I do it?

My html Code:

```
<button (click)="toggleAcc()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
    <ngb-accordion id="acc1" #acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="ngb-panel-0">
                <ngb-panel id="detailAcc">
                    <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
                        <span>&#9733; <b>Fancy</b> title &#9733;</span>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                       Hello World!!!!
                    </ng-template>
                </ngb-panel>
            </ngb-accordion>
```

I want some script for toggleAcc method

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.html'
})

toggleAcc(){
     **********Some Code Here that can collapse and expand accordion*********
}
```

I use Angular 14, bootstrap 5 and ng-bootstrap12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1: Provide panel id and toggle.**

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbAccordion } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@ViewChild('acc') acc: NgbAccordion;

toggleAcc() {
  this.acc.toggle('detailAcc');
}
```

**Solution 2: Iterate `panels` array to get all panel id and toggle each.**

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbAccordion } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@ViewChild('acc') acc: NgbAccordion;

toggleAcc() {
  for (let panelId of this.acc.panels.map((x) => x.id)) {
    this.acc.toggle(panelId);
  }
}
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gtcgje?file=src/app/accordion-basic.ts)